# I cant seem to figure out how to both rotate and collide a Rectangle in SFML ?

Tags: c++, sfml

Problem is, from what I can tell:

sf::FloatRect       - has intersection functionality, but no rotation?
sf::RectangleShape  - has no intersection functionaly?, but rotation

how do you get both functionality's of the one Rectangle type shape?

Please, Once I understand how both to have a Rectangle of some sort be collidable by intersection functionality and be able to be rotated.

Scenario: Some game sprites will rotate and a collisionBounds Rectangle must mirror the sprites rotation

thanks, I really need to understand this once and for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`sf::RectangleShape`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.2/classsf_1_1RectangleShape.php) has the methods `getGlobalBounds()` and `getLocalBounds()`, which return the enclosing [`sf::FloatRect`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.2/classsf_1_1Rect.php) that you should use for doing intersections.